# Bind an XAML event to class other than file root

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

Windows Phone 8 project, XAML. I have a ListBox inside a pivot item that's of my own class MyPivotItem (derived from vanilla PivotItem) inside a page. The listbox has an ItemTemplate with some controls. I'd like to bind an event in one of those controls to a method in MyPivotItem. The plain syntax `Click="OnClick"` does not work - the frameword searches for the method in the Page class only.

I could derive the control itself and do some trickery with tree navigation and event forwarding and so on, but I wonder if such a scenario can be served by XAML's internal means.

Is there any way to bind methods *non-programmatically* to a class that's deeper in the hierarchy than the root object of the XAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using something like behaviors or attached properties, it is not possible. XAML file is always associated with partial C# class and in this class you define your controls and events. For every Page.xaml, a Page.g.xaml file is generated that actually creates controls and binds events. However, those events must be defined in root object - the partial class itself.

Even if you create a workaround using either attached properties or behaviors, you are simply offloading that programmatic code to some other place and hiding it behind XAML syntax.

When would you want to bind to control's specific event handlers anyway? Can you simply use UserControls for that?